# Android studio setup

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to install android studio on my Macbook M1 chip but when it gets to this stage, I keeps on getting this error, I tried redownloading it but still have the same error:

java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image: Read
timed out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connection timed out error usually occurs when a client is trying to connect to a server, but the connection request is taking too long to complete. This can be caused by a variety of factors, including network congestion, firewall rules, or the server being down or overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Its a connection error. The error states that connection request to the server is taking more time that expected. Find a good internet connection and retry.